# Weak convergence in $L^2(0,T;X)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

In the book *Navier Stokes Equations* by Constantin and Foias, the folloiwng argument is made:

> Let $u_m$ converges weakly to $u$ in $L^2(0,T;V)$ where 
>   $$
> V=\overline{\{f\in (C_0^\infty(\Omega))^n\mid \nabla\cdot f=0\}}^{H^1(\Omega)}
> $$ By extracting a subsequence, we may assume that $u_m(t_0)$ converges to $u(t_0)$ weakly in $V$ for all $t_0\in[0,T]\setminus E$ for some $E$ of Lebesgue measure $0$.

For what conditions on a Banach space $X$ does one have the following general result?

> If $(u_m)$ converges weakly in $L^2(0,T;X)$ for some Banach space $X$, then it has a subsquence $u_{m_k}$ such that $u_{m_k}(t)$ converges weakly in $X$ for almost every $t\in[0,T]$.

Comment: As stated, this is not even true for X=R.

Comment: According to the comment of Michael Renardy, you have to specify more explicitly what you mean by "weak convergence". Perhaps this should mean $L^2$-convergence of $\varphi \circ u_m$ for all $\varphi\in X'$?

Comment: @JochenWengenroth: For "$u_m$ converges weakly in $Z:=L^2(0,T;X)$" I mean $f(u_m)$ converges for every $f$ in the dual of  $Z$.

Comment: Hence, Michael Renardy's comment applies.